# Reports and formula fields

Tags: reporting, formula-field, largedatavolumes

I read this very helpful article, [Designing Dashboards and Reports for Force.com Implementations with Large Data Volumes](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/08/designing-dashboards-and-reports-for-force-com-implementations-with-large-data-volumes.html?app_data=%7B%22pi%22%3a%22521d47a05dbbd21f36000002%22,%22pt%22%3a%22wall%22%7D)

I have one question regarding formula fields - if I use formula fields instead of deriving from a related object, how will it affect performance? are formula fields calculated on the fly when used in a Report?

Answer (score 3):

I have negative experience with using SOQL and formula fields when querying a larg amount of data. Because formula fields are calculated on the fly it can affect performance dramatically.

> Objects persisted in the database tend to have field types that store
>   data, for example numbers or text. *They can also have a formula field*
>   *type,* **which is calculated at run-time**

[An Introduction to Formulas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas)

> By default, formula fields don’t have underlying indexes, so they
>   require full scans to find target records. They also have to calculate
>   values on the fly because actual values are not stored in the
>   database. So when an object has a lot of records, queries that filter
>   using a formula field **can be painfully slow**.

[Best Practices: Nulls and Formula Fields](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html)